# Configure Wireless Network 12.10 Command Line

Tags: 12.10, wireless, command-line, server

Okay, so I've recently set up a server with Ubuntu Server 12.10 to run as a headless server.  When I ran the OS installer/setup it gave me an option to immediately connect to a wireless network (this box has a wireless card), and so I connected to my home network.  Since then I've turned the server on/off multiple times and it's always automatically connected to the wireless network until yesterday.

Usually I would SSH into the server, but yesterday I couldn't, so I hooked a keyboard and a monitor back up and learned that it wasn't connected to the wireless network.  Yesterday and today I attempted countless efforts to reconnect to the network from the command line based on advice from threads I found on google, but have been unsuccessful.

This is extremely frustrating: surely it shouldn't be this difficult? I'm tired of trying to edit my interfaces file.  Many of the threads I've found seem to date back quite a while. Can anyone please help out?

Comment: Can you post your interfaces file?

Comment: Sure!  Here's my interfaces file

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
       wpa-ssid <Wireless Network SSID>
       wpa-driver wext
#       wpa-psk  <non-hex password>
       wpa-ap-scan 1
       wpa-pairwise TKIP CCMP
       wpa-group TKIP CCMP
       wpa-proto WPA RSN
       wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
       wpa-psk <hex password>

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

Comment: Well that formatted itself terribly... Let me try that again
`# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <Wireless Network>
wpa-driver wext
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-pairwise TKIP CCMP
wpa-group TKIP CCMP
wpa-proto WPA RSN
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa-psk <hex key>

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Comment: Any help?  What could be causing this problem?

Comment: You may need to look at `dmesg | grep wlan0` for clues. Please don't dump the output into a comment, add it to the question with proper formatting, or use http://pastebin.com.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, confirm you have a working wireless card and driver:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Does it scan and see your network? Good. Next, if this is a server and you want to ssh into it, I wouldn't use DHCP, I suggest static. Then, I'd simplify your interfaces file quite a bit:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.110  <--an address outside the range of the DHCP server in the router
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-essid your_router
wpa-psk your_key
```

Of course, use the details appropriate to your network. Now restart the interface

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0
```

Did it get the address?

```
ifconfig
```

Can it connect?

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: Okay, so this was very helpful.  Made changes to my interfaces file and now the computer automatically connects to the network on startup, and when i try `ifconfig`, it says that it has been assigned the correct IP address.  `iwconfig` tells me it's connected to the network, however, it doesn't seem like DNS lookup is working.  When I try to ping google.com, I instead get the message `ping: unknown host google.com`.  Now what?

Comment: Am I embarrassed! I hope you corrected my mistake above: dns-nameservers and not the ham-handed dns-nameserers. Yikes. Please correct if not already. Can you ping by number? ping -c3 192.168.1.1 (or whatever your router address is) or ping -c3 8.8.8.8

Comment: I did correct the typo without even noticing; I suppose it's true that the brain only reads the first and last letters and then makes an educated guess.  I cannot ping by number...

Comment: When trying to ping by number I get the response `connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Is your wireless card working correctly? sudo iwlist wlan0 scan  If so, please double-check your interfaces file. You might also change to DHCP and check the address and route. If not, that's a separate question to troubleshoot the wireless.

Comment: iwlist scan is working perfectly.  What errors in my interfaces file would cause this?

Comment: Also, iwconfig shows that I'm not associated to any access point and not connecting to and ESSID

Comment: Any and every listing would cause an error. Is your wpa-essid correct? Linksys, for example, is not the same as linksys. Are the address and gateway numbers consistent with other computers on the same network? If you want to pastebin the file, disguising the key, of course, I'll be happy to check it. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Here's the file - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5592183/

Comment: Are there spaces in the SSID name? Please try this. Please note also, wpa-ssid; I've seen it both ways. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5593206/

Comment: I've tried those changes, but to no avail D:

Comment: Are there any clues in syslog? cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlan0 -e dhc  Does it connect with DHCP as attached?http://paste.ubuntu.com/5598922/